# How to check if JUnit test passed

Tags: java, junit

I have written a JUnit test `TestClass.test()` and in a certain other Java program which sees the test class I want to execute a certain part of the code only if the JUnit test passes. How can I do that? Something like

```
if(JUnit.passes(TestClass.test)){
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: @Progman Of course I have used Google before asking here. The problem with that is that you get all the time false results. Everybody cares about how JUnit works in the results I get. I know that already, my JUnit test works fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'd consider it a code smell if production code knows about tests, and for just running the tests there are test runners anyway.

Comment: @Robert I'm using JUnit not for testing my code (my code is fine) but I use it for testing the validity of external data. Now I have some procedure which works with the external data but shall only do so if the data is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically run the tests in a JUnit4 test suite and inspect the result with [JUnitCore.runClasses](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#runClasses(java.lang.Class...)):

```java
if (JUnitCore.runClasses(MyTests.class).wasSuccessful()) {
  System.err.println("Tests ran successfully.");
}
```

Or a single test with:

```java
if (new JUnitCore().run(Request.method(MyTests.class, "myTest")).wasSuccessful()) {
  System.err.println("Tests ran successfully.");
}
```

Comment: That seems to be the full test class. I'm interested in a single test from the class only.

Comment: Ok, I updated it.